# Mongodb Schema using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, primary-key

This is my user schema :

const userSchema = new Schema({

```
email: String,
username: String,
password: String,
secretToken: String,
active: Boolean,
type: String
```

}, {

```
timestamps: { // this will give us the detail when the account is created

    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
}
```

});

this is my requirement Schema:

const requirementSchema = new Schema({

```
name: String,
age: String,
class: String,
subject: String,
email: String
```

}, {

```
timestamps: { // this will give us the detail when the requiremnt is created

    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
}
```

});

how can I bring id from user schema to the requirement schema as secondary key?

Answer (score 0):

I think mongodb is not meant for relationship. I could led to very bad practice if your database grow. But you can try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef for Database References.

There is no primary key foreign key concept in Mongodb. and normalization is also discouraged in mongodb.

Comment: I know there is no primary key foreign key concept but i want to show relationship between these two schemas so how can i do that ?